# How to Add An array into Array index by index in iOS?

Tags: ios, arrays, json

i am newBie in iOS Development. i want to add my JSON Parsing Data Dictionary Array Key Value in to another array But it only Add My Last Array index in to New Array.

My Code like as

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
 if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    NSError* error;

    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.storeViewTable reloadData];
    }
    self.storeViewTable.hidden=FALSE;
    }
    NSMutableArray *imagearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (index=0; index <[self.imageArray count]; index ++)
    {
        for(NSDictionary *dict in self.imageArray )
        {
            imagearray = [dict valueForKey:@"demopage"];
            self.imagesa = imagearray;
        }
    }

     NSLog(@"Array Count %d",[self.imagesa count]);
     NSLog(@"Another array Count %d",[self.imageArray count]);
}
```

Here self.imagearray is my main array that contain my all JSON Data but i want to Parse A new Data From old Data And add it in to self.imagesa array here For self-images Value for key is demo page  and Self.imagearray count is Three(3) So i want all my Three Index value in to self.imagesa but it contain only Last index Value please Give me Solution For that.And my Webservices link is Here. [link](http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazine_list.php)

Comment: remove `imagearray = [dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]; self.imagesa = imagearray;` and  and add `[self.imagesa addObject: [dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]];` and i think you don't need `for (index=0; index <[self.imageArray count]; index ++)` this loop.

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani i write for(NSDictionary *dict in self.imageArray ){
 [self.imagesa addObject: [dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]];
            }

         NSLog(@"Array Count %@",self.imagesa); then it return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should look like below.

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if ([[json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[json objectForKey:@"data"];
    [imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
}

//do not alloc init if you have already alloc init array.
NSMutableArray *imagesa=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSDictionary *dict in imageArray )
{
    [imagesa addObject:@{@"demopage":[dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]}];
}

NSLog(@"Array Count %lu",(unsigned long)[imagesa count]);
NSLog(@"Another array Count %lu",(unsigned long)[imageArray count]);
```

and i got below output

> Array Count 3
>
> Another array Count 3

**NOTE**

and if you want to add all `demopage` dictionary to `imagesa` array then replace your for loop

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in imageArray )
{
    NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[dict valueForKey:@"demopage"];
    [imagesa addObjectsFromArray:arr];
}
```

and output is

> Array Count 69
>
> Another array Count 3

Comment: Here i want My three index array By index into self.imagesa means my array self.imegesa also contain three index because i want to print Three link images into DifferentView Controller

Comment: @AshishGabani can not understand what you're trying to say. on 1st type you'll get 3 counts for array in which. at 0 index you'll get 0 index demopagedata.

Comment: Bro here my self.image array Contain three index so each index have -demopage Key And i want to Add this -demopage Key value Based On my self.image index into self.imagesa means my main Array Have Three index so i want My self.imagearray have also three index and Here my Webservices link you show it then you understand http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazine_list.php

Comment: yes i understand i get First index data but i want all data based on index . means my Data also Contain Three index

Comment: @AshishGabani you mean you want array like (demopage=(index 0),demopage=(index 1),demopage=(index 2))?

Comment: Yes Bro i want it.but how it possible?

Comment: check my updated answer . add `[imagesa addObject:@{@"demopage":[dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]}];` in place of `[imagesa addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]];`
`

Comment: Bro now i want this Array to Show into another View based on index for that i write a code like this then i got only First index array(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
    {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger row = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"Tag of button %d",row);
    if (row == 1)
    {
        PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
        preview.imagesa=self.imagesa;
        [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];

     }
     }

Comment: `preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[0][@"demopage"];`

Comment: @Chintu Bro here My array index is only 3 then it is ooh but in future when Array index is increase then how i set row tag and index of array????please give me Solution as soon as possible.